# null object value when query user data from parse.com database

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

null object value when query user data from parse.com database

```
final ParseUser user= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (user!=null){
        Email.setText(user.getEmail());
        ParseFile file=user.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");
        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                Bitmap pic= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                Bitmap croped=getCroppedBitmap(pic);
                Bitmap scaled=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croped, 70, 70, true);
                ProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(scaled);

            }
        });

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

my app is showing only bitmap image where obtained email value is null on using `log.d("Email:",user.getEmail()+"")`
is there any problem in code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either the user did not enter an email, or the code to save the email to parse is incorrect.  Check on Parse to see if the value exists in your database for that user.  If it does maybe set a breakpoint at the line and inspect the `user` object you receive.

Comment: Yes user class in parse.com database have values of email